# Gson : deserialize time serialized by Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, gson, deserialization, date-format

Json string given by Jackson contains time as {"time":"19:31:00"}

I want to deserialize it using Gson to get the `java.sql.Time` object back.

What DateFormat should I set into gson?

Presently, I am using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a JSONDeserializer for `java.sql.Time` with Gson.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Time.class, new MyTimeJsonDeserializer()).create();
    MyTime time = gson.fromJson("{\"time\": \"19:31:00\"}", MyTime.class);
    System.out.println(time.getTime());
}

public static class MyTime{

    private Time time;

    public Time getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Time time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}

public static class MyTimeJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Time>{

    @Override
    public Time deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        String time = json.getAsString();
        String[] parts = time.split(":");
        return new Time(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to first get the date as a string, and then convert it to date using `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(timeStr)`